# Can't stop Symfony 2 repeated field from bubbling its errors?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I can't get the [repeated field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html) to not bubbling errors (for example, when fields don't match) to the parent main form. Here is the `$plain_password` property:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User implements
    \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\MinLength(limit=6)
     * @Assert\MaxLength(limit=32)
     */
    public $plain_password;
}
```

And the relevant part of the form:

```
$builder->add('plain_password', 'repeated', array(
    'type'        => 'password',
    'first_name'  => 'Password *',
    'second_name' => 'Conferma password *',
));
```

When user enters invalid values errors are passed to the parent form and rendered. See [Issue #1971](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1971), but it's supposed to be closed!

Comment: are you rendering the form in explicit way or via widget?

Comment: @DonCallisto rendering each row.

Comment: Take a look to my answer (don't know if I understand exactly your problem, but I think I got it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in Symfony 2.1, that's why the ticket is closed. Unfortunately it cannot be backported to 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you render fields in an explicit way, you can display only errors you are interested in by using this syntax

```
{{ form_errors(form.fieldName) }}
```

In that way you can use bubbling "util" only for fields you're intereted in or, if you won't any, simply don't put `form_errors` into your twig template.